# CsvMapper giving Exception while writing list to json file

Tags: java, jackson

I have a csv file which I need to bind it to bean and write it to the json file.I'm using jackson fasterxml .Its reading the data perfectly but while writing it to json using CsvMapper its giving exception-

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unrecognized column 'name':

I have created a simple pojo class of two fields name and address with getter and setters.

```
    public class Bean {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
    return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "Bean [name=" + name + ", address=" + address + "]";
    }}

    //in main method
    CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, false);


    CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(Bean.class).withHeader();

    QueAnsRead bean=null;
    MappingIterator<Map.Entry> it = mapper
            .readerFor(Bean.class)
            .with(schema)
            .readValues(csvFile);
            List<Bean> alist = new ArrayList<Bean>();
            while (it.hasNextValue()) {
                 beanRead = (Bean) it.nextValue();
                alist.add(beanRead);
            }

            for(Bean read:alist){
                System.out.println(read);
            }

         mapper.writeValue(new File("c:/testCSV/data.json"), alist);

    }
```

Comment: Can you show the Bean class?

Comment: I have added a bean class.please have a look

Comment: Can you also show the contents of your data.json file?